# How do I convert rows to columns, and repeat the adjacent cells?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I'm sorry if the title is confusing, but a visual should hopefully help:

Here's what my sheet looks like:

```
  A B C D
1 x y z t
2 q w e r
3 y u i o
```

I need to generate a separate sheet wherein:

```
  A B C
1 x y t
2 x z t
3 q w r
4 q e r
 ...
```

Basically, I need the middle two columns of the original sheet to be transposed and the adjacent columns to it pulled into my new sheet as well (as duplicate rows).

I have the transpose working correctly, and when I pull the adjacent columns that works too. The issue is, I can't autofill the sheet. When I try to drag & autofill, instead of autofilling using row 2 from the original sheet, the new sheet will autofill using row 3 (which is the same row # in the new sheet).

Please let me know if this isn't making sense, I'll try to explain better! I'm not very well versed in the Google Spreadsheets scripts - I've tried before but they seem rather cumbersome. But I'm happy to try that as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure where a transpose operation would come into play but a little conditional maths and the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a)¹ should suffice.

```
=INDEX($A$1:$D$3,(ROW(1:1)-1)/2+1,IF(COLUMN(A:A)=3,4,IF(AND(ISEVEN(ROW(1:1)),COLUMN(A:A)=2),3,COLUMN(A:A))))
```

[image: index_repeat_gs]

The documentation I've linked to is Excel but the syntax is identical for these purposes.

**Addendum for more columns**

By adjusting the condition for the offset after the third column, more columns can be readily accounted for.

```
=INDEX($A$1:$J$3,(ROW(1:1)-1)/2+1,IF(COLUMN(A:A)>=3,COLUMN(A:A)+1,IF(AND(ISEVEN(ROW(1:1)),COLUMN(A:A)=2),3,COLUMN(A:A))))
```

[image: index_offset_repeat]

The above collects 10 columns from the source matrix but should be auto-adjusting for pretty much any number of columns.

---

¹ <sub>The [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) accepts parameters for both row number and column number. Although typically only one of these is used, there is no restriction against supplying both against a 2D range of cells.</sub>

- <sub>Put the row_number calculation,
        `=(ROW(1:1)-1)/2+1`
   into a cell and fill down. You will receive 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, etc. This supplies the repeating row number from the A1:D3 range.</sub>
- <sub>Put the column_number calculation,
        `=IF(COLUMN(A:A)=3,4,IF(AND(ISEVEN(ROW(1:1)),COLUMN(A:A)=2),3,COLUMN(A:A)))`
   into a cell and fill right and down. You will receive 1, 2, 4 for the first row and 1, 3, 4 for the second. This pattern repeats itself for subsequent rows and supplies the offset column numbers from the A1:D3 range.</sub>

Comment: Now that's an `index` formula if I've ever seen one.

Comment: this is amazing! thank you so much. this is exactly what I want. the only issue is - my actual spreadsheet is 9 columns x around 8.5K rows. The rows I am pretty sure can deal with, but with 9 columns, I don't know how to extend the formula you've provided.

Thanks so much for your help, this is really promising - I have been stuck on this for a while!

Comment: @RingoBlancke - This is the problem with [Russian Doll Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188625). You asked a specific question and supplied specific data and I've answered that to the best of my ability. Now you want to change the conditions of the original question which invalidates my answer. With 9 columns I have no idea which or how many columns you need to have repeated. Suggest you use the explanation I've put in the addendum to try and produce the proper pattern for filling right; if you cannot then ask a new question with a complete description and sample data.

Comment: @Jeeped apologies - I didn't mean to be rude. The only columns that need to be repeated are the two in the middle, exactly same as the ones in my question. The thing I'm having a tough time with - the 5 other additional columns. I thought the answer to the small problem would easily translate to a solution to my actual issue, but I can't seem to work it out. I can accept you answer because it has helped me out, and ask a separate one if that is proper etiquette. Let me know what the best practice is.

Comment: @RingoBlancke - I've made a small adjustment that still alternates column s B and C for every second row but allows additional columns to the right.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with 3 single arrayformulas that are dynamic to work with any number of rows of data:

Here is an image to demonstrate:

[image]

The three formulas are:

`CELL A1:`

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(";",ARRAYFORMULA(REPT(Sheet1!A1:A&";",2))),";"))
```

`CELL B1:`

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(";",ARRAYFORMULA(Sheet1!B1:B&";"&Sheet1!C1:C)),";"))
```

`CELL C1:`

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(";",ARRAYFORMULA(REPT(Sheet1!D1:D&";",2))),";"))
```